# Error reading tmp file/directory when using NPM to include a GIT only package

Tags: npm

I am trying to include the GIT package https://github.com/Denglo/bs5-autocomplete-vanillaJS.git into my (simple) project. This currently only has two other packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "latest",
    "bootstrap-icons": "latest"
  }
```

Running a `npm install` with the above works without an issue, but when I run any of the following

```
npm install git+https://github.com/Denglo/bs5-autocomplete-vanillaJS.git
```

or

```
npm install https://github.com/Denglo/bs5-autocomplete-vanillaJS.git
```

or

```
npm install github:Denglo/bs5-autocomplete-vanillaJS
```

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path ~/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneHYQNgb/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '~/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneHYQNgb/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ~/.npm/_logs/2022-07-22T09_37_33_747Z-debug-0.log
```

The `~/.npm/_cacache/tmp` directory exists and the user has full access to it. The error log does not says the same as above. I also tried to manually add the line to the package.json, but that resulted in the same error.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: The repository lacks `package.json`. Is it `npm`-installable at all?

Comment: It is not installable directly as it isn't listed on npmjs. However, my understanding is that I can install it directly from the Github repository?

Comment: I am a Python programmer and don't know enough about `npm` packages. But I think no, you cannot. I suspect they added `package.json` for publishing at npmjs.com but forgotten to commit it; or even deliberately omitted.

Comment: Thank you for your help in any way. I too use npm as a tool and am not that familiar with all its idiosyncrasies unfortunately.